# Find solution set of $\mathbb{C}$-valued equation $y^{(4)}=2y^{(3)}-y''$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Problem:**

$\text{Find the solution set of this } \mathbb{C}\text{-valued equation }$
$$y^{(4)}=2y^{(3)}-y''$$
$\text{So we have } y^4=2y^3-y^2 \implies y=1\lor y=0$.

As the solution said, we have $\phi_1(x)=1, \phi_2(x)=x, \phi_3(x)=e^x, \phi_4(x)=xe^x$ and they are *linearly independent*.

$\mathscr{H}=\{c_1\phi_1+c_2\phi_2+c_3\phi_3+c_4\phi_4|c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4\in\mathbb{C}\}$

I have no idea where those $\phi$ come from, it'll be great, if some one could explain it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, are you familiar with kernel lemma ?

Comment: Let $y'' = z$, then the equation becomes $$z'' - 2z' + z = 0$$ then make the ansatz that $z = e^{\lambda x}$, find the $\lambda$ that satisfy the equation which determines $z$, then integrate twice to get $y$.

Comment: Yes, and it didn't deserve more "Answer" than this comment, did it? +@EDX I don't understand why you talk about the "kernel lemma". May be yours is not the same as [mine](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemme_des_noyaux)?

Comment: no, i'm not familiar with kernel lemma. This is a problem from old exam which was taught by another Prof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting $z(x)=y''(x)$ leads to
$$z''=2z'-z$$
so any solution $z^*(x)$ to this second-order linear equation with constant coefficients leads to a two-parameter family of solutions $y(x)=\iint z^*(x)+Ax+B$, explaining $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$.

The characteristic polynomial of the second-order equation factors as $(r-1)^2$, leading to $\phi_3(x)=e^x$ and $\phi_4(x)=xe^x$ as is the case when there are repeated roots.

Comment: thanks for the answer! and where does $\phi_1 \text{and }\phi_2$ come from.

Comment: @Malik Did you note the $Ax+B$ part? (Integrating zero gives polynomials.)

Comment: sorry, i didn't notice that.

Answer (score 1):

$$y^{(4)}=2y^{(3)}-y''$$
$$y^{(4)}-2y^{(3)}+y''=0$$
Rewrite the DE as:
$$(y''e^{-x})''=0$$
and integrate.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to explain it in an easier manner.

We can rewrite the equation as:
$$y^{(4)} - 2y^{(3)} + y^{"} = 0$$
We can express this as a characteristic polynomial to solve for the eigenvalues to the eigenfunction above.
$$ \lambda^4 - 2\lambda^3 + \lambda^2 = 0 $$
$$ \lambda^2(\lambda^2-2\lambda+1)=0 $$
$$ \lambda^2(\lambda-1)^2=0 $$
$$ \lambda_{1,2}=0, \lambda_{3,4}=1$$
We can observe that each root has a algebraic multiplicity of 2, respectively. Alternatively, we can say there are repeated roots.

Hence, the general solution to the ODE above is given by,
$$ y(x) = c_1e^{0x} +c_2xe^{0x} + c_3e^{x} +c_4xe^{x} = c_1 +c_2x + c_3e^{x} +c_4xe^{x} $$ where $c_1, c_2, c_3, c_4$ are constants.

As what you mentioned in your question about $\phi(x)$, the solution to your eigenfunction is represented by the basis $\{1,x, e^x,xe^x\}$ which is linearly independent.